# Segment direction in polar plane

Tags: geometry, algorithms, euclidean-geometry, polar-coordinates, euclidean-algorithm

I have the following situation: Base point (green) and segments, for each segment his vertices represented as polar point with theta angle from base point.

The problem: For each segment I have his 2 vertices theta's. Not ordered! I need just from this data to figure out the range of angles this segment overlaps. For example for the 2 vertices 45,330 belonging to the top segment, the correct answer is from 330 to 45 and NOT from 45 to 330.

EDIT:
The direction is from 0 to 359 or 1 to 360. But the problem is cyclic as you can see from the example of the top segment: 330 -> 45.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: With the remark "angles are measured clockwise", yes.

Comment: @zoli Thanks, yes the measurement is from 0 -> 359 (or 1 -> 360). Do you have answer for this situation?